# Pull To Refresh not showing loading animation

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I have used [this pull-to-refresh library](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh) in my project, with the following code:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:visibility="invisible" />      

       <com.markupartist.android.widget.PullToRefreshListView     
            android:id="@+id/list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="16dp"
            android:fadingEdge="none"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I see the example it works fine, it also shows the loading animation view.

But in my project, with the above code, its not showing the loading animation view.

```
listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    System.out.println("Pull to refresh called");
                    onRefreshClicked(); // To Refresh my list
                    listView.onRefreshComplete();
                }
            });
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your

```
listView.onRefreshComplete();
```

Because it stops the refresh loading when you are pull to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that particular library before, but do you have anything against using the one in Android's support library? Works perfectly for me...

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;
```

AND

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: I have not tried it, where can i find the example ?

Comment: The following links will shed some light on it's use: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/ http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/05/android-swiperefreshlayout-tutorial.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html